# GTX 660ti 3GB 2 monitors + TV

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card

I'm looking for information on how to do this properly. What I would like to accomplish is having my new GTX 660Ti 3GB drive my two 22" lcd monitors ( witch it does marvelously right now ) and also output video to my Vizio TV. The TV is a model XVT3D554SV. Both of my monitors are using the two DVI connectors. I tried linking my TV with an HDMI cable but I have not gotten any video on the screen nor has windows or the video driver utility ( i forget the name of it ) detected the TV being plugged in. I'm not looking to have output to the TV all the time I would just like to fire up steam's big picture mode and sit back on my couch sometimes. Have i done something wrong or am i trying to do something this card can not handle here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response from MSI tech support:

This card can only output to 2 display max using legacy connectivity (VGA, DVI, HDMI), unless if you use DisplayPort as your 3rd display then you can achieve three (3) display output

Let me be the first to say I am quite jaded when it comes to just about anyone's level 1 support. Now, I don't know the level of expertise of the person I got on the phone by calling ASRock but I did assume it was of the "level 1" variety. I was given the short, cover your bases answer and I admit was quite skeptical. Well, this is where I eat a bit of crow because it has solved the issue. The firmware update has produced a completely stable machine for over a week.

Guess there is a reason they throw those out as a first answer